# Errors when running code from command line which are not in PyCharm

Tags: python, linux, bash, shell

This question has been asked before, but none of the solutions seem to match my issue.

I have a bash script held in the same directory as the project root of my PyCharm. This contains this code:

```
#!/bin/bash

declare -a threshold=(some array of numbers);

for var in "${threshold[@]}"; do
      `python src/main/propertyPredictor.py data/triples.json data/sentenceMatrixFiltered.json data/output/predictedProperties.json $var`
      `python src/main/testFeatures.py data/featuresKept.json data/output/testLabels.json data/output/hyperTestLabels.json $var data/triples.json data/output/devLabels.json`
      `python src/main/logisticBagOfWords.py data/output/predictedProperties.json data/output/devLabels.json data/featuresKept.json data/output/evaluation.txt data/output/ data/output/summaryEval.csv`
done
```

Which is just a machine learning pipeline.

When I run each of the above one my one in PyCharm, I get no errors. However, when I run my bash script from my command line in the project root via `. scriptname.sh`or `sh scriptname.sh` or `bash scriptname.sh`, and also when I run each one on the command line, I get errors for each file:

For predictor.py, everything works fine, but when I run the second file, I get:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "src/main/testFeatures.py", line 214, in <module>
    testLabels = testSentenceLabels()
  File "src/main/testFeatures.py", line 154, in testSentenceLabels
    return dict_list
UnboundLocalError: local variable 'dict_list' referenced before assignment
```

As an example.

When I go through and run the actual bash script, I get errors for each line:

```
src/main/propertyPredictor.py:84: RuntimeWarning: divide by zero encountered in double_scalars
  return abs(numer-denom)/numpy.abs(float(denom))
src/main/propertyPredictor.py:84: RuntimeWarning: invalid value encountered in double_scalars
  return abs(numer-denom)/numpy.abs(float(denom))
-bash: loading: command not found
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "src/main/testFeatures.py", line 214, in <module>
    testLabels = testSentenceLabels()
  File "src/main/testFeatures.py", line 154, in testSentenceLabels
    return dict_list
UnboundLocalError: local variable 'dict_list' referenced before assignment
-bash: We: command not found
/Users/dhruv/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/sklearn/metrics/classification.py:958: UndefinedMetricWarning: Precision and F-score are ill-defined and being set to 0.0 in labels with no predicted samples.
  'precision', 'predicted', average, warn_for)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "src/main/logisticBagOfWords.py", line 329, in <module>
    testSet = str(os.path.splitext(sys.argv[2])[0]).split("/")[8]
IndexError: list index out of range
-bash: We: command not found
src/main/propertyPredictor.py:84: RuntimeWarning: divide by zero encountered in double_scalars
  return abs(numer-denom)/numpy.abs(float(denom))
src/main/propertyPredictor.py:84: RuntimeWarning: invalid value encountered in double_scalars
  return abs(numer-denom)/numpy.abs(float(denom))
-bash: loading: command not found
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "src/main/testFeatures.py", line 214, in <module>
    testLabels = testSentenceLabels()
  File "src/main/testFeatures.py", line 154, in testSentenceLabels
    return dict_list
UnboundLocalError: local variable 'dict_list' referenced before assignment
-bash: We: command not found
```

And this just loops through.

Here is my information on PyCharm interpreter:

```
import sys; print(sys.executable)
import os; print(os.getcwd())
import sys; print(sys.path)

/Users/dhruv/anaconda/bin/python
/Users/dhruv/Documents/university/ClaimDetection/src/main
['/Users/dhruv/Documents/university/ClaimDetection/src/main', '/Users/dhruv/Documents/university/ClaimDetection', '/Users/dhruv/anaconda/lib/python27.zip', '/Users/dhruv/anaconda/lib/python2.7', '/Users/dhruv/anaconda/lib/python2.7/plat-darwin', '/Users/dhruv/anaconda/lib/python2.7/plat-mac', '/Users/dhruv/anaconda/lib/python2.7/plat-mac/lib-scriptpackages', '/Users/dhruv/anaconda/lib/python2.7/lib-tk', '/Users/dhruv/anaconda/lib/python2.7/lib-old', '/Users/dhruv/anaconda/lib/python2.7/lib-dynload', '/Users/dhruv/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages', '/Users/dhruv/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/Sphinx-1.3.5-py2.7.egg', '/Users/dhruv/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/aeosa', '/Users/dhruv/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/setuptools-20.2.2-py2.7.egg']
```

And from the command line, running same commands:

```
/Users/dhruv/anaconda/bin/python
/Users/dhruv/Documents/university/ClaimDetection
['', '/Users/dhruv/anaconda/lib/python27.zip', '/Users/dhruv/anaconda/lib/python2.7', '/Users/dhruv/anaconda/lib/python2.7/plat-darwin', '/Users/dhruv/anaconda/lib/python2.7/plat-mac', '/Users/dhruv/anaconda/lib/python2.7/plat-mac/lib-scriptpackages', '/Users/dhruv/anaconda/lib/python2.7/lib-tk', '/Users/dhruv/anaconda/lib/python2.7/lib-old', '/Users/dhruv/anaconda/lib/python2.7/lib-dynload', '/Users/dhruv/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages', '/Users/dhruv/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/Sphinx-1.3.5-py2.7.egg', '/Users/dhruv/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/aeosa', '/Users/dhruv/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/setuptools-20.2.2-py2.7.egg']
```

Noting that there is a difference here, I first went into the python interpreter on my command line and did:

```
import sys
sys.path.append("/Users/dhruv/Documents/university/ClaimDetection/")
```

And so on.

Then I even added these lines to my `~./bash_profile` file:

```
PYTHONPATH=/Users/dhruv/Documents/university/ClaimDetection/location:$PYTHONPATH
PYTHONPATH=/Users/dhruv/Documents/university/ClaimDetection/src/main/location:$PYTHONPATH
export PYTHONPATH
```

Still I get the same errors in the second file.

Any ideas what I am doing wrong here? I also have a `/~.profile` file - I can include these if this might help...

Comment: Do the errors messages make sense?  For instance, is there a path through `testSentenceLabels` where `dict_list` is never assigned?

Comment: `We: command not found` is really weird as well.  What does the output of running the script with `sh -x` look like?

Comment: @nephtes I always assign `dict_list` as `dict_list = []` in a loop, hence like I say it runs fine in PyCharm.

Comment: @nephtes I did `sh -x`, I then get a prompt with `sh-3.2$:` then run `sh myfile.sh`. I get the same errors - the `dict_list` referenced before assignment and `We: command not found`.

Comment: Why the backticks in your script? Do you know what that means, or are you just typing randomly hoping something will "make it work"?

Comment: @DhruvGhulati Should've been more specific.  What happens when you type `sh -x myfile.sh`?  And yeah, why the backticks?

Comment: Ok the backticks have solved a few things, still getting `Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "src/main/testFeatures.py", line 214, in <module>
    testLabels = testSentenceLabels()
  File "src/main/testFeatures.py", line 154, in testSentenceLabels
    return dict_list
UnboundLocalError: local variable 'dict_list' referenced before assignment` and `testSet = str(os.path.splitext(sys.argv[2])[0]).split("/")[8]
IndexError: list index out of range`

Comment: I have a feeling the second error is because the command line sees a different argument to what I put into my PyCharm configurations for script parameters, however still not sure about the first error.

Comment: I fixed the above error just by assigning the variable later, but now I get new errors where large chunks of my code are not being run. Just a guess but does the fact that my code is run via calling functions within `if __name__ == "__main__":` only causing some issues?